# Creating heat/exciting molecules by controlling their gravity?

Tags: science-based, magic, energy

Had a character the ability to control the hypothetical Graviton, would it be possible they could move and excite molecules by altering their gravity enough to create heat? Enough for fire? Or is gravity simply too weak a force?

This isn’t a question about whether one can control gravity, and rather about it’s limitations. I’m no physicist, and have only a high school understanding of that physical laws with a smattering of research WAY above my head.

Thanks!

Comment: How much can your person amplify or dampen gravity? 2x? 10x 10000x? Put another way... is your character strong enough to hold themselves in zero G while on Earth (I.e float around inside our atmosphere)?

Comment: It's... unclear how manipulating *gravity* would be used to create heat... unless you're talking about compressing matter until it starts to fuse. I guess you could use this ability to move matter around and let friction do its thing, but that seems impractical. Heat is much more closely related to kinetic energy. I'd sooner believe a telekinetic heating (and cooling?) things.

Comment: @SRM They would be able to "float around inside our atmosphere," but nothing close to superman level flight; just simple levitation for probably a minute at max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity is the flimsiest of the forces we have around us. To make it noticeable one needs large masses.

A standard exercise in high school is to compare the gravitational attraction between a proton and an electron and their electrostatic attraction. If you do [the math](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/18-3-coulombs-law/), you will find that the electrostatic force is $10^{39}$ times stronger than the gravitation one.

In principle you can use altered gravity to enhance the interaction between atoms. In practice, given the factor above, you'd probably need so much effort that rubbing a stick would a much easier way to light a fire.

Comment: I think this is the first time I directly contradict L.Dutch.

Comment: Ah yeah, that was my fear. Do you think it would be safe enough to bank on the fact we simply don't know enough about gravitons to put a definitive limit on how they could be manipulated? (To what extent, I mean.) Also, let's assume (and I'll oversimplify it a lot just for discussion purposes) that it appears the law of conservation of mass is violated, and more gravitons can be involved in the interaction than already exist in the immediate area. Would it then be feasible?

Answer (score 4):

If you can levitate yourself (as stated in the question comments) then, **yes, you can create fire.** It doesn’t matter how flimsy gravity is... what matters is *how much of it you can bring to bear on an object.*

One way is obvious: take the total force needed to move a human body and apply that to move a piece of **flint against steel**... you’ll get sparks that can ignite flame. Less obvious is more internal friction: sliding a the top half of a team of paper back and forth against the other half, reversing direction rapidly. The **friction** can be built up to catch fire. It is just like rubbing sticks together. If you can do it small enough and fast enough, the movement of the paper doesn’t even have to be visible.

There are some industrial machines that can demo this: they can build up enough friction heat from vibration to melt metals, definitely enough to ignite paper or other flammable materials.

I don’t think you can plausibly do it to just agitate a fluid like gasoline... you’d need a human that can consciously think about and direct individual molecules. That breaks any suspension of disbelief for me: humans don’t do well focusing on more than seven objects at a time, and that with practice! But if there’s a pair of objects inside the gas tank that can be rubbed to create sparks or friction? That would work.

Note that doing the rubbing by hand or machine might be easier, but your powers would allow it at a distance or when your hands are tied.

This applies to gravity manipulation or any other force.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! As for the control of individual atoms, I have a solution, but it's a purely sci-fi thing and is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: At the extreme end of the scale: use your power to (slowly) push a ceramic coated tungsten telephone pole up to orbital height and velocity. At a point told to you by your tech-and-Kerbal savvy sidekick: push the telephone pole back down into the atmosphere. Depending upon what you hit you just started a literal and metaphorical firestorm.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can, but the point is not how much gravity you can generate, but more on how fast you can change it. My idea is basically the same of the one used by the microwave oven.

In that case ([Dielectric heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating)) the electromagnetic waves act on some molecules (like water) and produce rotations in them. Depending on the frequency of the waves this causes the molecules to keep on changing the direction of the rotation and to be pushed around by it, which causes collisions and generates heat.

In this case you need someone that is able to quickly change the gravity. For example going a million times in a second from no gravity to two times the one on earth. This won't cause any macroscopic change, but internally it should cause enough collisions to heat the thing up. The precise heat produced just depends on how much gravity he can generate and how fast he can go from one extreme to the other. I've got no estimations for how much it's required to start a fire, but I think it's theoretically possible.